# Variable changing itself?

Tags: python

So I am working on a project, and this bit of code is acting funny. I wanted a function that would take a list (list1) , make a copy (list2) of that list and trim certain objects from the copy only. I only wrote code to subtract items from the copy, be the original keeps getting changed as well.(?) I just don't understand how the original list (list1) is being subtracted from. Code underneath, thank you in advance for your help..

```
def copyandtrim(w, x, y, z):
    list1 = [w, x, y ,z]
    list2 = []
    list2 = (list1)

    testlen = (len(list2))

    for y in range(testlen - 1):
        if (list2[y])[2] == 0:
            list2.remove(list2[y])
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Hint: Using round brackets does NOT create a tuple! So the assignment `x = (y)` just binds the object `y` to the name `x`. To create a tuple you need a comma: `x = (y, )`. This is one of the ugly details in Python, but you'll have to get used to it ...

Answer (score 5):

In order to make a copy of `list1` in `list2` you should do this:

```
list2 = list1[:]
```

But be careful, using `list2.remove(list2[y])` changes `list2`, so further indexes are shifted as well. I would suggest this alternative to your loop:

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if x[2] != 0]
```

Comment: Using the slice operation seems widely carried but I don't find it exactly implicit, is there anything wrong with copying a list like this: `x = range(0, 3); y = list(x)` ? If seems more implicit imo

Comment: @user2298943 I think you mean explicit, rather than implicit. Both are fine.

Comment: thank you, but I don't understand the second piece of code you posted. How would it work to trim the list?

Comment: @user2786555 `list2` will be a new list generated by taking every element from `list1` if and only if `x[2] != 0`. So you can see it as a copy of `list1` but with every element where `x[2] == 0` removed.

Answer (score 2):

`list2 = list1` doesn't actually do a deep copy of the `list` object. It simply points `list2` to refer to **the same** list object. To get a copy, the easiest way is to use:

```
list2 = list1[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy list in python you should use slice operation:

```
list2 = list1[:]
```